# How do I set a storyboard from the XAML resources (in code behind)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I am new to using WPF, I have made an animated Expander (seems to be a popular first control :) ) using the blog post [here](http://ewilkerson.wordpress.com/2007/02/02/wpf-expander-control-cool-things-part-2-animation-and-auto-collapsing/), but I cannot seem to get the Storyboard from the Resources...

Here is my XAML:

```
<Expander xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="CustomControls.CustomExpanderControl"
             x:Name="ExpanderAnimated"
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="150" Height="24" Width="150" Opacity="0.5" Header="ExpanderAnimated">
    <Expander.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnExpanded">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderAnimated">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderAnimated">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="24"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="150"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnCollapsed">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderAnimated">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.5"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderAnimated">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="150"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="24"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Expander.Resources>
    <Expander.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Expander.Expanded"/>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Expander.Collapsed"/>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnExpanded}"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnCollapsed}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Expander.Triggers>

</Expander>
```

And the relevant code behind:

```
private Storyboard sbCollapsed
{
    get { return (Storyboard)this.Resources["OnCollapsed"]; }
    set { Resources["OnCollapsed"] = value; }
}
private Storyboard sbExpanded
{
    get { return (Storyboard)this.Resources["OnExpanded"]; }
    set { Resources["OnExpanded"] = value; }
}
private SplineDoubleKeyFrame CollapsedFromHeight
{
    get
    {
        return (SplineDoubleKeyFrame)
           ((DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames)sbCollapsed.Children[0]).KeyFrames[0];
    }
}
private SplineDoubleKeyFrame CollapsedToHeight
{
    get
    {
        return (SplineDoubleKeyFrame)
           ((DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames)sbExpanded.Children[0]).KeyFrames[1];
    }
}
private SplineDoubleKeyFrame ExpandedFromHeight
{
    get
    {
        return (SplineDoubleKeyFrame)
           ((DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames)sbCollapsed.Children[0]).KeyFrames[0];
    }
}
private SplineDoubleKeyFrame ExpandedToHeight
{
    get
    {
        return (SplineDoubleKeyFrame)
           ((DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames)sbExpanded.Children[0]).KeyFrames[1];
    }
}
```

(That is the whole XAML, I can post the whole c# if needed)

What do I need to change in the 2 `private StoryBoard` properties to set them correctly?

The exception is as follows:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

StackTrace

at CustomControls.ExpanderAnimated.get_CollapsedToHeight() // This is the private property as above
at CustomControls.ExpanderAnimated.get_CollapsedHeight() // This is the public property

InnerException: None
```

EDIT

This is happening in the Designer

I click on the Expander:
[image]

And it shows this exception:
[image]

EDIT2

So I changed the `Storyboard get {}` to return

```
FindResource("OnCollapsed") as Storyboard;
```

This throws the exception **ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException: 'OnCollapsed' resource not found.** ..... Except it is right there in the XAML!! grr

Comment: Which reference causes the exception (Storyboard, Children, etc.)?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is a custom control that I have added to another project. I figured I had done something obviously wrong :) Is there a way to step through the control code? I created it in Blend

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Blend, but if you debug the code in Visual Studio you can set a breakpoint in the setter that causes the exception and examine the objects involved.

Comment: The trouble is that this is happening in the Design window... I have just tried adding a new form to the controls solution and adding it to that, but even with breakpoints it doesn't stop, just clears the form and shows that exception message

Comment: Might be the Designer isn't capable of resolving all the references correctly. Can you acutally run the code?

Comment: The code is being run when I select the custom control in the Designer, the only problem is I have no way of setting a break point... If I run the form, the Expander behaves as the normal version does, with no animation